# Why is there a gap on the top of my webpage?

Tags: css, html, padding, margin

I'm sure the answer is obvious, but I haven't been working with html/css that much...

There is a gap of white space in between the top of the browser and the first div.  I don't really get why the gap is there.  I didn't use margin-top or padding-top or border-top in the css, so why is there a gap?

Thanks!

Comment: Show some html/css so we can figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: Wow you guys are fast and on the mark! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: use reset sheet http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Can you add some minimal amount of html/css to the question to repro the problem before you accept an answer?  Your question will be worth an upvote then, IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it would be extremely helpful if you actually posted some code or a link to the site, I would assume it's just the default padding.  Most browsers have default styles for things like `body` that you may want to clear.  Try something like this:

```
html, body{
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

If that doesn't fix it you'll need to give more information.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing anything I'd imagine you either need to clear the default padding on the body element or you have a heading tag in that div that is adding some extra goodness.

Are you using a reset? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

if the page is wrapped with a wrapper, use:

```
 #wrap{
     margin:0 auto;
     padding:0
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again, some context would be nice but if these solutions aren't cutting it, then there's a good change your a victim of collapsing margins.  Try setting the overflow property of the body to auto

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Floating the upper divs solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was fixed when I added 30px of padding to my div container. I used

```
   .top-container {
       padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

My problem happened after I set some images to an absolute position in my div (which had a position of relative.) For some reason that gap appeared, but setting the padding worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 9 years old but...
body { margin:0; }
type that in between the  Tags and it should work

Comment: First containing element will need their top margin set to zero e.g. <p style="margin-top:0;">...