# Why does my html tag have a height of 8px?

Tags: html, css

Just:

```
<html>
<head></head> //there is content in here
</html>
```

by itself shows `html` has a height of `8px` (according to Chrome). Why is this?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you seeing it has a height of 8px?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a gap on the top of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475883/why-is-there-a-gap-on-the-top-of-my-webpage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most browsers including Chrome the `body` element has `margin:8px` by default.  This is what you see.

**It is only 8px and not 16px**  (8px top + 8px bottom added together) because of **collapsing margins**. There is no content so the top and bottom margins are "collapsing" together.

A `body` element is added automatically even though you didn't put it in your HTML, if you inspect it in Chrome you will see it and also where the *user agent stylesheet* is adding the 8px:

[image: Chrome inspector]

If you inspect this snippet, the height will be 0:

```css
body { margin:0;}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
</html>
```

Or inspect this snippet and the height will be 20px;

```css
body { margin: 20px 0 0 0;}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @user1601324 I didn't even see that Chrome had automatically added in a `body` for me!

Comment: @tonitone120 Yes Chrome tries to fix "broken" html. I had added a screen image of the inspector for your code in Chrome so you can see what Chrome is doing to it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the application author's stylesheet for the `<body>` element comes with a margin of 8px (or similar). So the default of the `<body>` element (which is a mandatory element and, thus, will automatically be added by the browser) will look like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 1ex;">
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: The default style of `margin: 1ex;` may alternatively be added to the `<html>` element itself. It depends on the browser manufacturer's preference.

Comment: Thanks @AxD, are you using `ex` unit as presented here? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Comment: Yes. That's because usually `ex`/`em` length values are used instead of `px` length values because they scale along when the user changes the webpage zoom.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think that Chrome might just assign a default value because once I was doing something with rows where I needed to put floating-left, and I didn't so in chrome and on mozilla would look different